# Flutter error setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. when use Getx GetxController update

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

i have a Counter widget the code like this

```dart
import 'dart:math' as math;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:erp_app/icons/PlutusIcons.dart';

class Counter extends StatefulWidget {
  final int? value;
  final ValueChanged<int>? onValueChanged; 
  final int? maximum;
  final int? minimum;
  final double? buttonSize;
  final double? textSize;
  final bool? editable; 
  final TextEditingController? customTextController;

  Counter({
    Key? key,
    this.value,
    this.maximum,
    this.minimum,
    this.onValueChanged,
    this.buttonSize,
    this.textSize,
    this.editable,
    this.customTextController,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CounterState createState() => _CounterState();
}

class _CounterState extends State<Counter> {
  int _currentValue = 0;
  TextEditingController _textController = TextEditingController();
  FocusNode _textFocusNode = FocusNode();

  @override
  void didUpdateWidget(covariant Counter oldWidget) {
    if (widget.value != null) {
      _currentValue = _verifyInputVal(widget.value!);
      _textController.text = _currentValue.toString();
      _notifyValueChange(_currentValue);
    }
    super.didUpdateWidget(oldWidget);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    
    if (widget.customTextController != null) {
      _textController = widget.customTextController!;
    }
   
    _handleFocusNodeEvent();

    int initValue = widget.value ?? 0;
    initValue = _verifyInputVal(initValue);
    _currentValue = initValue;
    _textController.text = initValue.toString();
    _notifyValueChange(initValue);
    super.initState();
  }


  @override
  void dispose() {
   
    if (widget.customTextController == null) {
      _textController.dispose();
    }

    _textFocusNode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _handleFocusNodeEvent() {
    _textFocusNode.addListener(() {
      if (_textFocusNode.hasFocus == false && widget.editable != null && widget.editable == true) {
        
        setState(() {
          _textController.text = _currentValue.toString();
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void _increase() {
    if (widget.maximum != null && _currentValue >= widget.maximum!) {
      return;
    }

    _currentValue += 1;
    _notifyValueChange(_currentValue);
    setState(() {
      _currentValue = _currentValue;
      _textController.text = _currentValue.toString();
    });
  }

  void _decrease() {
    if (widget.minimum != null && _currentValue <= widget.minimum!) {
      return;
    }

    _currentValue -= 1;
    _notifyValueChange(_currentValue);
    setState(() {
      _currentValue = _currentValue;
      _textController.text = _currentValue.toString();
    });
  }

  bool _increaseIsDisabled() {
    if (widget.maximum == null) {
      return false;
    }

   
    return widget.maximum != null && _currentValue >= widget.maximum!;
  }

  bool _decreaseIsDisabled() {
    if (widget.minimum == null) {
      return false;
    }

    
    return widget.minimum != null && _currentValue <= widget.minimum!;
  }

  
  int _verifyInputVal(int val) {
    int result = 0;
    int? minimum = widget.minimum;
    int? maximum = widget.maximum;

    if (minimum != null) {
      result = math.max(minimum, val);
    }
    if (maximum != null) {
      result = math.min(result, maximum);
    }

    return result;
  }

  void _notifyValueChange(int value) {
    widget.onValueChanged?.call(value);
  }

  void _inputOnChange(String val) {
    int? num = int.tryParse(val);
    if (num == null) {
      return;
    }

   
    _currentValue = _verifyInputVal(num);
    if (widget.onValueChanged != null) {
      widget.onValueChanged!(_currentValue);
    }

    setState(() {
      _currentValue = _currentValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: IconButton(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: widget.buttonSize ?? 20.0,
                minHeight: widget.buttonSize ?? 20.0,
              ),
              color: _decreaseIsDisabled() ? Colors.black45 : Colors.blue,
              disabledColor: Colors.grey,
              onPressed: _decreaseIsDisabled() ? null : _decrease,
              icon: Icon(
                PlutusIcons.decrease,
                size: widget.buttonSize ?? 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 5.0),
            width: 80.0,
            child: TextFormField(
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              controller: _textController,
              focusNode: _textFocusNode,
              onChanged: _inputOnChange,
              enabled: widget.editable ?? false,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: widget.textSize,
              ),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: IconButton(
              constraints: BoxConstraints(
                minWidth: widget.buttonSize ?? 20.0,
                minHeight: widget.buttonSize ?? 20.0,
              ),
              color: _increaseIsDisabled() ? Colors.black45 : Colors.blue,
              disabledColor: Colors.grey,
              onPressed: _increaseIsDisabled() ? null : _increase,
              icon: Icon(
                PlutusIcons.plus,
                size: widget.buttonSize ?? 20.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and i use this widget in my GetxPage

```dart
class page extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetBuilder<PageLogic>(
        init: PageLogic(), 
        logic => Counter(
          editable: true,
          value: logic.systemStockNum,
          buttonSize: 28.0,
          minimum: 0,
          onValueChanged: logic.handleCounterChange,
    ));
  }
}
```

i pass a valueChanged callback into the Counter widget and then when the changeHandler call, i will change my GetxController property and update

```dart
class PageLogic extends GetxController {
  int currentValue = 0;

  void handleCounterChange(int value) {
    currentValue = value;
    update();
  }
}
```

and then the error is emit, how the error to resolved? and why the error is rasied?

Answer (score 0):

It means you are try to refresh the page even while the initial widget is already loading.

To prevent calling setState during build method is already in progress, you can check whether your initial widget is mounted properly before calling setState. For doing that just wrap your setState by if statement like this :

```
 if(mounted){
   setState((){

   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call methods inside initState if some method would rebuild some widgets that are being rendered.

To solved that you should use onReady method from the controller.

You should move all your variables to the controller class.

```
class PageLogic extends GetxController {

  int currentValue = 0;
  // move all your veriables here (TextEditingControllers, all)


  @override
  void onReady(){

   make you logic for initialization here
   

   super.onReady();
  }


  void handleCounterChange(int value) {
    currentValue = value;
    update();
  }



}
```

Retrieve the controller and use inside your page

```
final pageLogic = PageLogin();
```